# Solving Linear Programming in positive integer domain

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a question in my math textbook where I had to find maximum solution to this linear programming problem:

$$ 4x-3y>=0 \\
3x+2y<=30 \\
x>=0 \\
y>=0 $$

So I got non-integer solution $(2+(8/11)$ and $10+(10/11))$.

What should I do if I want positive integer solution instead of fractional solution?

EDIT : The objective function which I want to find maximum solution in my problem $f(x)=5x+3.5y$ with the maximum value is $51.818.181,8181$

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum solution"? You haven't given an objective function.

Comment: Maximum solution = maximum objective function value

Comment: Linear programming is about continuous problems so you can expect fractional solutions. Integer programming (and "mixed integer programming") is about finding integer solutions.

Comment: So is it possible to truncate solutions in linear programming if required?

Comment: No, rounding is in general not a valid approach